# Creating a table using Win32 API

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, frameworks

I've been searching the net for different things about the win32 API, but it seems all information on it is rather sparse.

I am looking to create a simple window that shows a list of items, however I want to display different columns of data for each item, in a table-style format, where the user could perhaps be allowed to resize the different column widths.

If at all possible, I'd like to also be able to change the background colors of different rows, in the code, between just a general white, red, yellow, or green.

And the user would also be allowed to right click different rows, and be able to call a function on them, or copy the data to the clipboard (but that part is a different story).

Now, I've found list-viewer objects(?) that can be placed in the window, buttons, and right-click menus... but I cannot figure out how to do a table, using the Win32 API.  I haven't even really read up on background colors for anything other than the window itself, either.

Is there a different, better framework I should use for this, or are there some functions or items that I've been missing?  All help or guidance on the idea would be appreciated...

I'm using MSVC++ to do... everything that I'm working on.

Comment: What development environment are you using? (It helps figure out what might be available for you to use.)

Comment: I'm working in MSVC++, sorry, you're right, I should have said that...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Windows provides a fairly basic collection of built-in controls, listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773169%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If you want something more sophisticated your options are:

- Code it yourself.  You have to paint it yourself, handle all the user-interaction, the scrolling, etc.  This is a big job.
- Find an existing implementation.
- Abandon VC++ and use WinForms or WPF.

If you're stuck with VC++, [The Grid Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/523/The-Grid-Control) and [The Ultimate Grid](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20183/The-Ultimate-Grid-Home-Page) are MFC-based.

If you're not using MFC there's [BABYGRID](http://www.codeguru.com/Cpp/controls/controls/gridcontrol/article.php/c5277) or [The Win32 SDK Data Grid](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38168/Win32-SDK-Data-Grid-View-Made-Easy).

If none of them suit, you'll have more luck searching for "grid" than "table".

Answer (score 15):

Using the windows API and the standard control ListView you can do a table using the style LVS_REPORT

documentation link - unfortunatelly with no code :( -

[About List-View Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774735%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I've found this good article [Windows Programmierung: List View](http://www.willemer.de/informatik/windows/winlistv.htm)
the explanation is in german language but a google translation together with the code should be enough to understand it. From the article, to create the window:

```
#include "commctrl.h"

InitCommonControls();
hwndList = CreateWindow(WC_LISTVIEW, "", 
         WS_VISIBLE|WS_BORDER|WS_CHILD | LVS_REPORT | LVS_EDITLABELS, 
         10, 10, 300, 100, 
         hWnd, (HMENU)ID_LIST, hInst, 0);
```

then it is explained how to create the columns in the method

```
int CreateColumn(HWND hwndLV, int iCol, char *Text, int iWidth)
```

how to insert an item (one column)

```
int CreateItem(HWND hwndList, char *Text)
```

or insert item with two columns

```
int Create2ColItem(HWND hwndList, char *Text1, char *Text2)
```

etc...

Comment: Dude, this is the best solution for the question. Really strange the answer selected is trying to steer away from stock solution.

Comment: Also sample code in MSDN on [Adding LV Items & SubItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298346%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Answer (score 5):

For Listview examples, nothing beats the clarity of the [Classic Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/controls/common/vlistvw/VListVw.c)!

In the meantime, Google Translate along with Unicode + tiny modifications to the rescue for @Alejadro's German link for the [Listview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20810102/2128797)- there's no direct translation on offer from search results as the page doesn't contain the appropriate [meta tag](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en). Snipped a little for brevity:

**Subsequent changes of styles**

The style of a ListView can be changed after creation. For this the functions GetWindowLong and SetWindowLong are used. About masks different styles can be defined.

> Mask.................................Masked Styles:
>   LVS_TYPEMASK..............LVS_ICON, LVS_LIST, LVS_REPORT and LVS_SMALLICON
>   LVS_ALIGNMASK.............LVS_ALIGNLEFT and LVS_ALIGNTOP
>   LVS_TYPESTYLEMASK...LVS_ALIGNLEFT and LVS_ALIGNTOP but also VS_NOCOLUMNHEADER and LVS_NOSORTHEADER

For the following sequence, dwView contains the style to use, such as `LVS_REPORT or LVS_ICON`.

```
DWORD dwStyle = GetWindowLong(hwndLV, GWL_STYLE); // get current style
if ((dwStyle & LVS_TYPEMASK)! = dwView) // only on change
SetWindowLong(hwndLV, GWL_STYLE, (dwStyle & ~ LVS_TYPEMASK) | dwView); }
```

**Control of the ListView control**

**Generating a list**

A list view is created with the CreateWindow function. The window class uses the constant `WC_LISTVIEW`. To do this, the common control header file must be included.

```
#include "commctrl.h"

InitCommonControls();
hwndList = CreateWindow(WC_LISTVIEW, "",
  WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | LVS_REPORT | LVS_EDITLABELS,
  10, 10, 300, 100,
  hWnd, (HMENU) ID_LIST, hInst, 0);
```

In the dialog, it is simply defined in the resource.

If there are unresolved externals, you should check whether the library for the Common Controls (comctl32.lib) is included.

**Columns of the ListView**

Before something can be inserted in a `REPORT`, the columns must be defined. A column is described by the structure `LVCOLUMN`. The following routine creates a column.

```
int CreateColumn(HWND hwndLV, int iCol, char * text, intwidth)
{
LVCOLUMN lvc;

lvc.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_SUBITEM;
lvc.fmt = LVCFMT_LEFT;
lvc.cx = iWidth;
lvc.pszText = text;
lvc.iSubItem = iCol;
return ListView_InsertColumn(hwndLV, iCol, & lvc);
}
```

The columns can be modified by messages to the ListView or by calling macros that will ultimately execute a SendMessage.

```
Message            Macro call                                    Function
LVM_INSERTCOLUMN   ListView_InsertColumn(HWND, int, LVCOLUMN * ) Insert column
LVM_DELETECOLUMN   ListView_DeleteColumn(HWND, int)              Delete column
LVM_GETCOLUMN      ListView_GetColumn(HWND, int, LVCOLUMN * )    Get properties of the column
LVM_SETCOLUMN      ListView_SetColumn(HWND, int, LVCOLUMN * )    Change properties of the column
LVM_GETCOLUMNWIDTH ListView_GetColumnWidth(HWND, int)            Determine column width
LVM_SETCOLUMNWIDTH ListView_SetColumnWidth(HWND, int, int)       Set column width
```

**Insert a line**

An element of the ListView is described by the structure `LVITEMW` (see below). Each element can be represented as an `ICON`, `SMALLICON`, `LIST` element or as the left column of a `REPORT` line.

```
int CreateItem(HWND hwndList, wchar_t * text)
 {
 LVITEMW lvi = {0};
 lvi.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
 lvi.pszText = text;
 return ListView_InsertItem(hwndList, & lvi);
 }
```

The mask field determines which elements of the `LVITEMW` structure are really used. Since it often makes sense to keep a pointer to the memory object that holds the data behind the object, the lParam field is useful. In order for this to be used, `LVIF_TEXT | LVIF_PARAM` must be set as a mask.

The constants of mask and the fields that enable them:

> LVIF_IMAGE iImage
>   LVIF_INDENT iIndent
>   LVIF_PARAM lParam
>   LVIF_STATE state
>   LVIF_TEXT pszText

**The further columns of a report**

The element itself is always left in the report view and is selectable. To fill more columns, a text is added to the item.

```
int Create2ColItem(HWND hwndList, wchar_t * Text1, wchar_t * Text2)
{
LVITEMW lvi = {0};
int Ret;
// Initialize LVITEMW members that are common to all items.
lvi.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
lvi.pszText = Text1;
Ret = ListView_InsertItem(hwndList, & lvi);
if (Ret >= 0)
{
ListView_SetItemText(hwndList, Ret, 1, Text2);
}
return Ret;
}
```

The above `Create2ColItem` is best demonstrated by something along the line of the following statements:

```
    LVHwnd = Your_Create_LV_Routine();
    if (LVHwnd)
    {
    CreateColumn(LVHwnd, 0, ptrColHeaderString1, iColSize1);
    CreateColumn(LVHwnd, 1, ptrColHeaderString2, iColSize2);
    Create2ColItem(LVHwnd, ptrItemText1, ptrItemText2);
    }
```

**The structure LVITEMW**

The structure `LVITEMW` (in *CommCtrl.h*) describes an element of the ListView. The most important elements are briefly described here. First the definition:

```
typedef struct tagLVITEMW
{
  UINT mask;
  int iItem;
  int iSubItem;
  UINT state;
  UINT stateMask;
  LPWSTR pszText;
  int cchTextMax;
  int iImage;
  LPARAM lParam;
  #if (_WIN32_IE >= 0x0300) //historical note for IE3 users!
  int iIndent;
  #endif
  #if (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_WINXP)
    int iGroupId;
    UINT cColumns; // tile view columns
    PUINT puColumns;
  #endif
  #if (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_VISTA)
    int* piColFmt;
    int iGroup; // readonly. only valid for owner data.
  #endif
} LVITEMW, *LPLVITEMW;
```

The `LVM_GETITEMW` and `LVM_SETITEMW` messages change the attributes of an element. As a parameter, you get a pointer to a `LVITEMW` structure next to the `HWND` of the ListView, which must be filled in advance.

The structural elements in detail:

*Mask*:
Specifies which elements are used. A combination of the following flags is possible:

> LVIF_IMAGE iImage
>
> LVIF_INDENT iIndent
>
> LVIF_PARAM lParam
>
> LVIF_STATE state
>
> LVIF_TEXT pszText

*iItem*
Index (0-based) of the item to which the structure relates.

*iSubItem*
Index (1-based) of the subitem to which the structure relates. 0 if the structure refers to an item instead of a subitem.

*pszText*
points to a null-terminated string. If the value is `LPWSTR_TEXTCALLBACK`, it is a callback item. If this changes, pszText must be set to `LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK` and the ListView informed by `LVM_SETITEMW` or `LVM_SETITEMTEXT`.
`pszText` must not be set to `LPWSTR_TEXTCALLBACK` if the ListView has the style `LVS_SORTASCENDING` or `LVS_SORTDESCENDING`.

*cchTextMax*
Size of the buffer when the text is read.

*iImage*
Index of the icon of this element from the image list.

*lParam*
32-bit value that is specific to this element.

**Actions with elements**

> LVM_INSERTITEM Insertion of an element
>   LVM_DELETEITEM Delete an element
>   LVM_DELETEALLITEMS Delete all elements
>   LVM_GETITEMW Read properties of the element
>   LVM_GETITEMTEXT Read text of the element
>   LVM_SETITEMW change
>   LVM_SETITEMTEXT Change to the text

Before inserting multiple items, an `LVM_SETITEMCOUNT` message will be sent to the ListView indicating how many items will ultimately be contained. This allows the ListView to optimize its memory allocation and release. How many elements a ListView contains can be determined with `LVM_GETITEMCOUNT`.

**Editing selected elements**

```
int Pos = -1;
LVITEMW Item;
Pos = ListView_GetNextItem(hwndList, Pos, LVNI_SELECTED);
while (Pos> = 0)
{
Item.iItem = Pos;
Item.iSubItem = 0;
ListView_GetItem(hwndList, & Item);
TuWasMitElement((Element Type * ) Item.lParam);
Pos = ListView_GetNextItem(hwndList, Pos, LVNI_SELECTED);
}
```

**Events**
The ListView sends `WM_NOTIFY` messages to the parent window. The code can take the following values:

> Message............ Description
>   LVN_BEGINDRAG.............Start a drag-and-drop action
>   LVN_BEGINRDRAG..........Start a drag-and-drop action with the right mouse button
>   LVN_BEGINLABELEDIT....Start editing a label
>   LVN_ENDLABELEDIT.......End edit of a label
>   LVN_DELETEITEM..........Reports that the item is deleted
>   LVN_DELETEALLITEMS..Reports that all items are deleted
>   LVN_COLUMNCLICK......Indicates that the user clicked in the header of a report display
>   LVN_GETDISPINFO.......The control requests information about the presentation from the parent window
>   LVN_SETDISPINFO.......The information of the parent window for the item must be renewed
>   LVN_INSERTITEM..........Indicates the insertion of an item
>   LVN_ITEMCHANGED.....Indicates that an item has been changed
>   LVN_ITEMCHANGING....Indicates the intended change of an item
>   LVN_KEYDOWN.............Key was pressed

**Editing the labels**
The list view must have been created using the `LVS_EDITLABELS` style. Then a label can already be clicked on and inputs are accepted. However, the input is discarded immediately afterwards. To allow changes in the label, you just need to catch the `WM_NOTIFY` and return `TRUE`. In order to access the entered text in between, access is made to the text of the item. The example shows the input in a message box.

```
case WM_NOTIFY:
 switch (((LPNMHDR) lParam) -> code)
 {
  case LVN_ENDLABELEDIT:
  pItem = (NMLVDISPINFO) lParam;
  MessageBox (hWnd, pItem-> item.pszText, "entry", MB_OK);
  return TRUE;
```

If editing was aborted, the `pszText` element will be 0.

If you want to prevent editing, the message `LVN_BEGINLABELEDIT` is caught and returned `TRUE`. Here, too, the item can be accessed in the same way via `lParam` and thus, for example, a certain item group can be excluded.

**Click on the column header in the ListView**

```
case WM_NOTIFY:
 switch (((LPNMHDR) lParam) -> code)
 {
 case LVN_COLUMNCLICK:
 ColumnNr = ((LPNMLISTVIEW) lParam) -> iSubItem;
 .....
```

**Selection Event**

The `LVN_ITEMACTIVATE` event is sent when the user activates an item. As with the other ListView events, it achieves the window function as part of a `WM_NOTIFY` message.

```
case WM_NOTIFY:
switch (((LPNMHDR) lParam) -> code)
{
case LVN_ITEMACTIVATE:
HWND hwndFrom = (HWND) ((LPNMHDR) lParam) -> hwndFrom;MarkedItemIndex = 
ListView_GetNextItem(hwndFrom, -1, LVNI_SELECTED);
.....
```

The `LVM_GETSELECTEDCOUNT` message can be used to determine how many items have been activated. The `LVM_GETNEXTITEM` message is sent with the `LVNI_SELECTED` attribute and all items have been edited.

Comment: Your answer is very detailed in explaining the win32 ListView api. I myself have put together a class that makes creating, adding items, etc on a ListView easier. However win32 ListView is very limited and may not support this task(create a table of data). win32 ListView is designed as a one dimensional list. Even in report mode, only one column is selectable and editable. Every other column is just additional information. Which is pretty dumb. You will have to subclass ListView to make it work better, and that requires alot of research of effort.