# Building an excel like data grid in a windows application in C++

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I need to create a window application that has an excel grid that users can enter data into, via keyboard or cut and paste. I would like to be able to expand and contract it in both axes on the fly. I'm just starting out programming windows applications, so any pointers to examples or keywords that I can refine my search with, would be extremely helpful.

Thanks,
James

Comment: Move to C# and embed an Excel file into your app. Problem solved.

Comment: Our experience with automation under .NET was very far from optimal. Excel was very prone to crash. The lighter MFC COM interface worked fairly well, instead.

Comment: There are a bunch of suggestions in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966330/creating-a-table-using-win32-api/8967061#8967061

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [The Ultimate Grid](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20183/The-Ultimate-Grid-Home-Page). It has lots of features.

**EDIT:**
It used to be a commercial product, but it was later open sourced

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MFC, take a look at [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8/MFC-Grid-control-2-27) for data grid control. I've used it several times and it did the job.