# Display an array using Win32 api c++

Tags: c++, arrays, winapi

I am getting financial data from Yahoo finance and I want to display them in a window using the win32 api.
Right now I'm using a ListBox to add every row I have extracted from Yahoo but the result is not really aesthetic. This is what I get:
[image: Output using ListBox]

And another problem with the ListBox is that the user can't select only one value, the entire row is selected, I would like to be able to copy only value.

Did someone know a way to display an arraylike that with win32 api ?
The only way I see is to create a window with one Edit box for each value but it's look like a lot of trouble..

Comment: I think that table data should be displayed using a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966330/creating-a-table-using-win32-api), not a list.

Comment: From the [List Box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/list-boxes) documentation: *"A list box is a control window that contains a simple list of items from which the user can choose. For more complex lists, use the [List View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/list-view-control-reference) instead."*

Comment: *Did someone know a way to display an arraylike that with win32 api ?* -- Of course it can be done.  You are running programs written for Windows that displays data "nicely", correct?  They may have not used the Windows API directly, but indirectly, practically all programs make API calls in some way.

Comment: @IInspectable I had no knowledge about List view, it looks a lot like I am trying to get. I will look into it, thank you !